# $load tab content from another page to my page display ONLY first 4 image

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Page with issue: https://373834.myshoptet.com/80-104-cm/

JS code on page:

```
<div class="slider-in-80-104-cm">&nbsp;</div>
<script>$(".slider-in-80-104-cm").load("/ #products-27")</script>
```

Load tab content from: https://373834.myshoptet.com - Tab under id #products-27 (see in source code on page)

In Shoptet.cz is possible add products in TITLE PAGE to bs tabs - see in title page. I Need this products in categories (like 80-104-cm etc.)

I use jquery $load content from title page tabs to certain pages (products categories), but on categories pages is loaded ONLY first 4 products **with images**, but next products is loaded **WITHOUT images**.

If i change position of products in shoptet admin, always not displayed image on fifth and next products.

Instead product image is in source code this: `src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

Answer (score 0):

It's caused because Shoptet lazyloads all images except first row (4 by your settings).
All you need is to call `unveilImages();` after your load, or manually switch images at data-src to src.

Comment: Can you please guess how to do it? I can't change anything there manually, I can only edit the js code in the category. Thanks.

Comment: may i disable lazy load on category page with code:  $('img').each(function(){$(this).attr('src',$(this).data('original'));}); ? How to write the code please?

Comment: just use a callback for your load function, something like `$('.selector').load('url', function(){ unveilImages(); } );` should probably work